# Why set can be assigned to the variable but not arguments

Tags: scala

Unlike List is immutable convariance, Set is invariant function, I have an interesting codes I dont understand what is the reason behind it

```
class Fruit
case class Apple() extends Fruit

val foo: Set[Fruit] = Set(Apple())  // Compile success but why ? Set is an invariant

def doStuff(x: Set[Fruit]) = {}
val appleSet: Set[Apple] = Set(Apple())
doStuff(appleSet) // Compile failed but why ? assign to a value is fine
```

Is that failure reason (Set[Apple]) not triggering type inference ?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following line indeed compile fine:

```
val foo: Set[Fruit] = Set(Apple())
```

The reason is inference. The expression `Set(Apple())` appears in a context where a `Set[Fruit]` is expected, so when the compiler
sees that no type parameter was ecplicitely given to `Set.apply`, it will infer this type parameter to be `Fruit`. So in the end it is as if you had:

```
val foo: Set[Fruit] = Set[Fruit](Apple())
```

Which is perfectly correct.

Now if you do this, it will fail to compile, as expected:

```
scala>val foo: Set[Fruit] = Set[Apple](Apple())
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
found   : scala.collection.immutable.Set[Apple]
required: Set[Fruit]
```

Or even this:

```
scala> val foo = Set(Apple())
foo: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Apple] = Set(Apple())

scala> val bar: Set[Fruit] = foo
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Set[Apple]
 required: Set[Fruit]
       val bar: Set[Fruit] = foo
                             ^
```

In the latter case, `foo` is inferred to `Set[Apple]` instead of `Set[Fruit]`, 
because we have not specified any explicit type for `foo`, so there is no context for inference, and the most specific type (least upper bound) is inferred.

As for the call to `doStuff` in your example, it actually compiles fine. You probably made another mistake somewhere.